# Parsing XLS and XLSX (MS Excel) files with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, excel

Are there any gems able to parse XLS and XLSX files? I've found Spreadsheet and ParseExcel, but they both don't understand XLSX format.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I recently needed to parse some Excel files with Ruby. The abundance of libraries and options turned out to be confusing, so I wrote a [blog post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/03/22/parsing-excel-files-ruby/?utm_source=stackoverflow-ao&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=parsing-excel-files-ruby) about it.

Here is a table of different Ruby libraries and what they support:

[image]

If you care about performance, here is how the `xlsx` libraries compare:
[image]

I have sample code to read xlsx files with each supported library [here](https://github.com/mattnedrich/ruby-excel-library-examples)

Here are some examples for reading `xlsx` files with some different libraries:

**rubyXL**

```
require 'rubyXL'

workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse './sample_excel_files/xlsx_500_rows.xlsx'
worksheets = workbook.worksheets
puts "Found #{worksheets.count} worksheets"

worksheets.each do |worksheet|
  puts "Reading: #{worksheet.sheet_name}"
  num_rows = 0
  worksheet.each do |row|
    row_cells = row.cells.map{ |cell| cell.value }
    num_rows += 1
  end
  puts "Read #{num_rows} rows"
end
```

**roo**

```
require 'roo'

workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open './sample_excel_files/xlsx_500_rows.xlsx'
worksheets = workbook.sheets
puts "Found #{worksheets.count} worksheets"

worksheets.each do |worksheet|
  puts "Reading: #{worksheet}"
  num_rows = 0
  workbook.sheet(worksheet).each_row_streaming do |row|
    row_cells = row.map { |cell| cell.value }
    num_rows += 1
  end
  puts "Read #{num_rows} rows" 
end
```

**creek**

```
require 'creek'

workbook = Creek::Book.new './sample_excel_files/xlsx_500_rows.xlsx'
worksheets = workbook.sheets
puts "Found #{worksheets.count} worksheets"

worksheets.each do |worksheet|
  puts "Reading: #{worksheet.name}"
  num_rows = 0
  worksheet.rows.each do |row|
    row_cells = row.values
    num_rows += 1
  end
  puts "Read #{num_rows} rows"
end
```

**simple_xlsx_reader**

```
require 'simple_xlsx_reader'

workbook = SimpleXlsxReader.open './sample_excel_files/xlsx_500000_rows.xlsx'
worksheets = workbook.sheets
puts "Found #{worksheets.count} worksheets"

worksheets.each do |worksheet|
  puts "Reading: #{worksheet.name}"
  num_rows = 0
  worksheet.rows.each do |row|
    row_cells = row
    num_rows += 1
  end
  puts "Read #{num_rows} rows"
end
```

Here is an example of reading a legacy `xls` file using the `spreadsheet` library:

**spreadsheet**

```
require 'spreadsheet'

# Note: spreadsheet only supports .xls files (not .xlsx)
workbook = Spreadsheet.open './sample_excel_files/xls_500_rows.xls'
worksheets = workbook.worksheets
puts "Found #{worksheets.count} worksheets"

worksheets.each do |worksheet|
  puts "Reading: #{worksheet.name}"
  num_rows = 0
  worksheet.rows.each do |row|
    row_cells = row.to_a.map{ |v| v.methods.include?(:value) ? v.value : v }
    num_rows += 1
  end
  puts "Read #{num_rows} rows"
end
```

Comment: This was a great post and I upvoted, but unfortunately I found that neither roo nor spreadsheet worked with my .xls data.

Comment: Thnks @guero64 The xls functionality for roo is actually kept in a different project called roo-xls https://github.com/roo-rb/roo-xls. Did you try that library?

Comment: I found the problem.  The source that was generating the files was saving them as .xls, but the content was HTML.  Thanks for your input, though.

Comment: Did you find any that did a reasonable job with defined names as ranges? E.g. with openpyxl: https://gist.github.com/empiricalthought/3f0b3a501720b87d4a4c4f0b7e372e62

Comment: Great work of comparision ! I am trying to use roo and I was wandering if you managed to extract comments from a cell, and how to achieve this with the provided function ?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck parsing locked Excel files? In most cases I would have the password.

Answer (score 57):

Just found [roo](https://github.com/Empact/roo), that might do the job - works for my requirements, reading a basic spreadsheet.

Comment: roo certainly works, but it's frustratingly un-Ruby-like and (for me, anyway) very surprising: not being able to iterate over rows using each? not being able to iterate over sheets? a notion of a "default sheet" followed by access to cells through the workbook object?

Comment: It took me a while to find, but [this now-official roo fork](https://github.com/Empact/roo), which you have to explicitly pin, fixes my complaints about roo. It has #each, #to_a, reasonable sheet access, and doesn't pollute the global namespace with `Spreadsheet` by requiring ruby-spreadsheet.

Comment: @woahdae Awesome! It'd be great to see an example with these new features. Is there any documentation available? I'm specifically interested in being able to iterate through each row of each worksheet of a workbook.

Comment: The README of that fork has an extra section about what is new in the fork. However, after implementing an xlsx upload requiring good typecasting, I found that roo typecasting had much to be desired. It choked when trying to parse "2" (formatted as a number) as a date. I wrote my own parser that I like much better, I'll upload it to github tonight and get back to you.

Comment: @woahdae Good stuff. Looking forward to seeing your work. Please send the link when you can.

Comment: Man, I wish I found this post sooner and this was a railscasts video too.

Answer (score 44):

The [roo](https://github.com/Empact/roo) gem works great for Excel (.xls and .xlsx) and it's being actively developed.

I agree the syntax is not great nor ruby-like. But that can be easily achieved with something like:

```
class Spreadsheet
  def initialize(file_path)
    @xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file_path)
  end

  def each_sheet
    @xls.sheets.each do |sheet|
      @xls.default_sheet = sheet
      yield sheet
    end
  end

  def each_row
    0.upto(@xls.last_row) do |index|
      yield @xls.row(index)
    end
  end

  def each_column
    0.upto(@xls.last_column) do |index|
      yield @xls.column(index)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Careful with this naming convention - Spreadsheet is an existing constant referring to a module: `Spreadsheet.class # => Module` Renaming the class to something like "Roobook" solves this issue. However, great work!

Comment: Latest roo (on the empact fork you point to) doesn't pollute the namespace, and comes with #each and such. Finally! yay empact.

Comment: Roo gem is terrible with large files. Opening a 5MB XLSx file can take 30-60 seconds which is just does not make any sense.

Comment: Roo takes a long time because it has to load everything into memory. It also seems to parse the spreadsheet into a usable data structure which can be slow.

Comment: Please where in a rails project can such a file be kept @Bruno Buccolo.

Comment: @lilfancy It's up to you. It could be `app/models` or something custom :)

Answer (score 27):

I'm using creek which uses nokogiri. It is fast. Used 8.3 seconds on a 21x11250 xlsx table on my Macbook Air. Got it to work on ruby 1.9.3+. The output format for each row is a hash of row and column name to cell content:
{"A1"=>"a cell", "B1"=>"another cell"}
The hash makes no guarantee that the keys will be in the original column order.
https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/creek

dullard is another great one that uses nokogiri. It is super fast. Used 6.7 seconds on a 21x11250 xlsx table on my Macbook Air. Got it to work on ruby 2.0.0+. The output format for each row is an array:
["a cell", "another cell"]
https://github.com/thirtyseven/dullard

simple_xlsx_reader which has been mentioned is great, a bit slow. Used 91 seconds on a 21x11250 xlsx table on my Macbook Air. Got it to work on ruby 1.9.3+. The output format for each row is an array:
["a cell", "another cell"]
https://github.com/woahdae/simple_xlsx_reader

Another interesting one is oxcelix. It uses ox's SAX parser which supposedly faster than both nokogiri's DOM and SAX parser. It supposedly outputs a Matrix. I could not get it to work. Also, there were some dependency issues with rubyzip. Would not recommend it.

In conclusion, creek seems like a good choice. Other posts recommend simple_xlsx_parser as it has similar performance.

Removed dullard as recommended as it's outdated and people are getting errors/having problems with it.

Comment: This post should be number one

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I found that streaming 100K+ rows from an XLSX file fast and memory efficient using the Dullard gem.

Comment: `dullard` was full of errors for me (with non latin data). `creek` gave what i need

Comment: okliv, it would be awesome if you could specify which typesets did not work with dullard here. Also, shoot of a post to the dullard issue tracker on github! :)

Comment: This answer mentions only reading 'xlsx' files, what about 'xls' files ?

Comment: seems like 'dullard' gem has some bug. It was reading the 'xlsx' file incorrectly in my case, whereas 'creek' worked fine. I am using rvm version 2.2.2 . Will not suggest others to use "dullard"

Comment: The 'dullard' gem will fail if you require it before requiring 'date'. In addition, there are other bugs. There is no doc and it hasn't been updated in over 3 years. I couldn't get it to access rows from a simple spreadsheet.

Comment: @frediy I've updated simple_xlsx_reader to be much faster, FYI (in my experience, the fastest now)

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for more modern libraries, take a look at Spreadsheet: http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html.
I can't tell if it supports XLSX files, but considering that it is actively developed, I'm guessing it does (I'm not on Windows, or with Office, so I can't test).

At this point, it looks like [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) is a good option again. It supports XLSX, allows (some) iteration by just using `times` with cell access. I admit, it's not pretty though.

Also, RubyXL can now give you a sort of iteration using their `extract_data` method, which gives you a 2d array of data, which can be easily iterated over.

Alternatively, if you're trying to work with XLSX files on Windows, you can use Ruby's Win32OLE library that allows you to interface with OLE objects, like the ones provided by Word and Excel. **However**, as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned in the comments, this has a few major drawbacks:

- Excel must be installed
- A new Excel instance is started for each document
- Memory and other resource consumption is far more than what is necessary for simple XLSX document manipulation.

But if you choose to use it, you can choose not to display Excel, load your XLSX file, and access it through it. I'm not sure if it supports iteration, however, I don't think it would be too hard to build around the supplied methods, as it is the full Microsoft OLE API for Excel.
Here's the documentation: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222101
Here's the gem: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html

Again, the options don't look much better, but there isn't much else out there, I'm afraid. it's hard to parse a file format that is a black box. And those few who managed to break it didn't do it that visibly. Google Docs is closed source, and LibreOffice is thousands of lines of harry C++.

Comment: Very helpful info! I'm currently building an excel crawler and having fits with it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044357/file-system-crawler-iteration-bugs#comment19404489_14044357). I've given up on roo as iteration is rather painful. However, I'm anxious to try `extract_data` with RubyXL.

Comment: Using OLE for XLSX is a *bad* idea -  XLSX is just compressed XML with a well known format.. It is definitely **not** a black box - the Open XML format is very well defined, the Open XML SDK provides all the information required to create the XML by hand *and* there are a lot of libraries that greatly simplify working with XLSX.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Interesting point. While I certainly see why that would be better, is there any reason (again, out of curiosity) why using OLE is so bad? I haven't used or developed for Windows in a few years, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: What you call OLE is the Automation interface for Excel - it requires Excel to be installed on the server and actually starts it up for *each* file request. It's slow - every call is am out-of-process call to Excel. It's also dangerous, as forgetting to close an instance means an Excel instance will stay in memory. This can quickly eat up server resources. In fact, XLSX was created so that any application could create a valid Excel file without requiring Excel on the server. The overhead is minimal - it's just XML processing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Right. I forgot that OLE was more IPC than a library. Thanks! I'll add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I've been working heavily with both Spreadsheet and rubyXL these past couple weeks and I must say that both are great tools. However, one area that both suffer is the lack of examples on actually implementing anything useful. Currently I'm building a crawler and using rubyXL to parse xlsx files and Spreadsheet for anything xls. I hope the code below can serve as a helpful example and show just how effective these tools can be.

```
require 'find'
require 'rubyXL'

count = 0

Find.find('/Users/Anconia/crawler/') do |file|             # begin iteration of each file of a specified directory
  if file =~ /\b.xlsx$\b/                                  # check if file is xlsx format
    workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse(file).worksheets       # creates an object containing all worksheets of an excel workbook
    workbook.each do |worksheet|                           # begin iteration over each worksheet
      data = worksheet.extract_data.to_s                   # extract data of a given worksheet - must be converted to a string in order to match a regex
      if data =~ /regex/
        puts file
        count += 1
      end      
    end
  end
end

puts "#{count} files were found"
```

---

```
require 'find'
require 'spreadsheet'
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'

count = 0

Find.find('/Users/Anconia/crawler/') do |file|             # begin iteration of each file of a specified directory
  if file =~ /\b.xls$\b/                                   # check if a given file is xls format
    workbook =  Spreadsheet.open(file).worksheets          # creates an object containing all worksheets of an excel workbook
    workbook.each do |worksheet|                           # begin iteration over each worksheet
      worksheet.each do |row|                              # begin iteration over each row of a worksheet
        if row.to_s =~ /regex/                             # rows must be converted to strings in order to match the regex
          puts file
          count += 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

puts "#{count} files were found"
```

Comment: How do I iterate over rows?? Possible?

Answer (score 4):

The [rubyXL](http://github.com/gilt/rubyXL) gem parses XLSX files beautifully.

Comment: rubyXL (like roo, above) also gets weird when you actually get around to accessing the data in a worksheet. Is there something fundamental about the data model for a spreadsheet that iteration over rows and columns cannot be simply provided?

Comment: RubyXL is a mess. I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a satisfactory xlsx parser. RubyXL doesn't do date typecasting, Roo tried to typecast a number as a date, and both are a mess both in api and code.

So, I wrote [simple_xlsx_reader](https://rubygems.org/gems/simple_xlsx_reader). You'd have to use something else for xls, though, so maybe it's not the full answer you're looking for.

Comment: looking forward to giving this a go. Hope to see more features down the road. Great start!

Comment: I've updated simple_xlsx_reader to be fast & memory efficient now, too

Answer (score 3):

Most of the online examples including the author's website for the Spreadsheet gem demonstrate reading the entire contents of an Excel file into RAM. That's fine if your spreadsheet is small.

```
xls = Spreadsheet.open(file_path)
```

For anyone working with very large files, a better way is to *stream-read* the contents of the file. The Spreadsheet gem supports this--albeit not well documented at this time (circa 3/2015).

```
Spreadsheet.open(file_path).worksheets.first.rows do |row|
  # do something with the array of CSV data
end
```

CITE: https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet

Comment: You 'll have to add .each if you want something to happen

Answer (score 2):

The [RemoteTable library](http://github.com/seamusabshere/remote_table) uses [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) internally. It makes it easy to read spreadsheets of different formats (XLS, XLSX, CSV, etc. possibly remote, possibly stored inside a zip, gz, etc.):

```
require 'remote_table'
r = RemoteTable.new 'http://www.fueleconomy.gov/FEG/epadata/02data.zip', :filename => 'guide_jan28.xls'
r.each do |row|
  puts row.inspect
end
```

Output:

```
{"Class"=>"TWO SEATERS", "Manufacturer"=>"ACURA", "carline name"=>"NSX", "displ"=>"3.0", "cyl"=>"6.0", "trans"=>"Auto(S4)", "drv"=>"R", "bidx"=>"60.0", "cty"=>"17.0", "hwy"=>"24.0", "cmb"=>"20.0", "ucty"=>"19.1342", "uhwy"=>"30.2", "ucmb"=>"22.9121", "fl"=>"P", "G"=>"", "T"=>"", "S"=>"", "2pv"=>"", "2lv"=>"", "4pv"=>"", "4lv"=>"", "hpv"=>"", "hlv"=>"", "fcost"=>"1238.0", "eng dscr"=>"DOHC-VTEC", "trans dscr"=>"2MODE", "vpc"=>"4.0", "cls"=>"1.0"}
{"Class"=>"TWO SEATERS", "Manufacturer"=>"ACURA", "carline name"=>"NSX", "displ"=>"3.2", "cyl"=>"6.0", "trans"=>"Manual(M6)", "drv"=>"R", "bidx"=>"65.0", "cty"=>"17.0", "hwy"=>"24.0", "cmb"=>"19.0", "ucty"=>"18.7", "uhwy"=>"30.4", "ucmb"=>"22.6171", "fl"=>"P", "G"=>"", "T"=>"", "S"=>"", "2pv"=>"", "2lv"=>"", "4pv"=>"", "4lv"=>"", "hpv"=>"", "hlv"=>"", "fcost"=>"1302.0", "eng dscr"=>"DOHC-VTEC", "trans dscr"=>"", "vpc"=>"4.0", "cls"=>"1.0"}
{"Class"=>"TWO SEATERS", "Manufacturer"=>"ASTON MARTIN", "carline name"=>"ASTON MARTIN VANQUISH", "displ"=>"5.9", "cyl"=>"12.0", "trans"=>"Auto(S6)", "drv"=>"R", "bidx"=>"1.0", "cty"=>"12.0", "hwy"=>"19.0", "cmb"=>"14.0", "ucty"=>"13.55", "uhwy"=>"24.7", "ucmb"=>"17.015", "fl"=>"P", "G"=>"G", "T"=>"", "S"=>"", "2pv"=>"", "2lv"=>"", "4pv"=>"", "4lv"=>"", "hpv"=>"", "hlv"=>"", "fcost"=>"1651.0", "eng dscr"=>"GUZZLER", "trans dscr"=>"CLKUP", "vpc"=>"4.0", "cls"=>"1.0"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked to handle large xlsx data recently, and creek library worked to parse large data than others, I recommend [CREEK](https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/creek) library well!

This is code to parse large xlsx data

> gem install creek

```
require 'creek'
creek = Creek::Book.new './blog_analytics/input/Performance_by_Page_2022-07-01_2022-07-31.xlsx'
sheet = creek.sheets[0]

index = 0
sheet.rows.each do |row|
    #handle row data
end
```