# File system crawler - iteration bugs

Tags: ruby, regex, spreadsheet, web-crawler

I'm currently building a file system crawler with the following code:

```
require 'find'
require 'spreadsheet'
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'

count = 0

Find.find('/Users/Anconia/crawler/') do |file|           
  if file =~ /\b.xls$/                                            # check if filename ends in desired format
    contents =  Spreadsheet.open(file).worksheets
    contents.each do |row|
      if row =~ /regex/
        puts file
        count += 1
      end
    end
  end
end

puts "#{count} files were found"
```

And am receiving the following output:
`0 files were found`

The regex is tested and correct - I currently use it in another crawler that works.

The output of `row.inspect` is

`#<Spreadsheet::Excel::Worksheet:0x003ffa5d418538 @row_addresses= @default_format= @selected= @dimensions= @name=Sheet1 @workbook=#<Spreadsheet::Excel::Workbook:0x007ff4bb147140> @rows=[] @columns=[] @links={} @merged_cells=[] @protected=false @password_hash=0 @changes={} @offsets={} @reader=#<Spreadsheet::Excel::Reader:0x007ff4bb1f3b98> @ole=#<Ole::Storage::RangesIOMigrateable:0x007ff4bb126fa8> @offset=15341 @guts={} @rows[3]>` - certainly nothing to iterate over.

Comment: I haven't used Spreadsheet.  Are you sure that `row` is a string containing your data?  Or is it an object for that row containing cells of which you want the first cell's contents?

Comment: I believe @PhilipHallstrom is correct, this is a case where irb will be your friend

Comment: @Anconia If you're feeling lazy and don't want to figure out how to do it in irb, then just add a `puts row.inspect` line just above you `if row =~` line and see what comes out...

Comment: `contents` is not a worksheet, it's all worksheets in the file. You should iterate over `contents` to get each sheet, then over each sheet to get each row.

Comment: Rather than pasting the results here, please paste them into the question itself so formatting is not lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Diego mentioned, I should have been iterating over contents - really appreciate the clarification! It should also be noted that `row` must be converted to a string before any iteration takes place.

Comment: That is not true. You don't need to convert to a string before you iterate over the row. Glad you figured it out though!

Comment: @BlaineOmega You are correct. Let me rephrase that - in order for the regex to match the test data, `row` must be converted to a string. Cheers and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
content = Spreadsheet.open(file)
sheet = content.worksheet 0 
sheet.each do |row|
...
```