# Is there any Ruby gem to read both .xls and .xlsx files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby, rubygems

As I have known, there are some Ruby gems to read .xls and .xlsx files.

**rubyXL**: read .xlsx and .xlsm files

**spreadsheet**: read .xls file

Also know some gems to write an excel file.

**axlsx**: only write .xlsx file

But I couldn't find any gem to read both file types.

Does anyone know?

Comment: I found this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321011/parsing-xls-and-xlsx-ms-excel-files-with-ruby

I haven't found an analysis more recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success using [roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) with the [roo-xls](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo-xls) extension.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!