# How to convert each sheet in an excel file into separate csv file using bash

Tags: excel, bash, csv, unix

I have this excel file with 15 sheets and I want to convert all the sheets into different csv files, ie 15 sheets ==> 15 csv files. I need to do this on a unix environment where I have limited permission. I can't use python or similar for this matter. How can I achieve this using bash script with minimum installation/changes to the environment? I can see 'apt-get' is there in the system. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why cannot you use Python? You can write main logic of converting excel to csv inside python and then call python script inside bash if you want to do something else as well.

Comment: I do not have permission to install the python libraries needed for excel conversion.

Comment: I don't have an answer but running a google search on `convert excel spreadsheets to csv files bash script` brings up a lot of hits; granted, many of the suggestions require installing some software which you'll need to determine if doable in your environment ...

Comment: bash itself can't do it. You'll need a language with an excel library. For instance, perl can use [`SpreadSheet::ParseXSLX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX) from CPAN; or [for ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321011/parsing-xls-and-xlsx-ms-excel-files-with-ruby). Whichever language you choose, you should be able to install libraries into your home directory, so "I don't have privileges" should not apply. If this requirement is for your job, you have to be able to use the tools you need, so raise this up the chain of command.

Comment: @bpaulo, did you try installing python libraries? How did you try? What happened when you tried - got any error messages? I would use `pip install` for that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert one particular file of CSV then it can be exported through the files and could be saved through the csv if multiple files have to be converted then: -
Press F5 key, select the folder contains the Excel files you want to convert to CSV files in first popping dialog.
Click OK, then in the second popping dialog, select the folder to place the CSV files.
Click OK, now the Excel files in the folder have been converted to CSV files and saved in another folder.

Comment: I want to accomplish this through bash script.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the binary of [csvtk](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/usage/#xlsx2csv), uncompress it in a folder and than give it execute permission.

Than you can run `csvtk xlsx2csv -a input.xlsx` to have list of the sheets. Then you can build a bash loop to convert every sheet to csv, changing for every loop the sheet number `csvtk xlsx2csv -i 1 input.xlsx >1.csv` (here is `1`).

If you want to use the sheet name it's `csvtk xlsx2csv input.xlsx -n "sheetName" >sheetName.csv`