# Fastest way to read the first row of big XLSX file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, roo-gem

I need to be able to read the first (header) row in big xlsx file (350k x 12 cells, ~30MB) very fast in Ruby on Rails app.
I am using Roo gem at the moment, which is fine for smaller files. But for files this big it takes 3-4 minutes. Is there a way to do this in seconds?

```
xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file_path)
sheet = xlsx.sheet(0)
header = sheet.row(1)
```

Edit:

- I tried other gems:

  - rubyXL took several minutes
  - creek was the fastest with 30s. But still unusable in controller

Edit2:

- I ended up using creek in a job and polling for the result in controller. Thx [Tom Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954610/tom-lord) for suggesting creek

Comment: Maybe it will not change the parsing time dramatically, but there was a comparison of different parsers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321011/parsing-xls-and-xlsx-ms-excel-files-with-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ruby gem `roo` does not support file streaming; it reads the whole file into memory. Which, as you say, works fine for smaller files but not so well for reading small sections of huge files.

You need to use a different library/approach. For example, you can use the gem: [`creek`](https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/creek), which describes itself as:

> a Ruby gem that provides a fast, simple and efficient method of parsing large Excel (xlsx and xlsm) files.

And, taking the example from the project's README, it's pretty straightforward to translate the code you wrote for `roo` into code that uses `creek`:

```
require 'creek'
creek = Creek::Book.new(file_path)
sheet = creek.sheets[0]
header = sheet.rows[0]
```

Note: A quick google of your StackOverflow question title led me to [this blog post](https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/how-to-efficiently-process-large-excel-files-using-ruby) as the top search result. It's always worth searching on Google first.

Comment: I have been using creek gem for many years and it's wonderful and it's very fast as the description says, this gem can be installed only with devkit.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried rubyXL, which took several minutes and I tried creek, which was the fastest with 30s. But still unusable in controller

Comment: @GTO I haven't actually tried running this with a large file, but *in theory* the idea of `creek` is that you can *stream* the file instead of reading the whole thing into memory. Does your code look something like the above, calling `Creek::Book.new`, or are you still trying to read the whole file into memory?

Comment: Yea, I am calling `Creek::Book.new`, this line still takes about 30s

Answer (score -1):

Using `#gets`could work, maybe something like:

```rb
first_line_data = File.open(file_path, "rb", &:gets)
first_line_file = File.open("tmp_file.xlsx", "wb") { |f| f << first_line_data }
xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open("tmp_file.xlsx")
# etc...
```

Comment: This would work on a plain-text `csv` file, but not on a binay `xlsx` file. You cannot call `gets` on the file to obtain "the first row of the first sheet".